# Automatically generate a CustomStringConvertible implementation for any Object

Tags: swift, customstringconvertible

I have to write a lot of code like this:

```
extension MyData: CustomStringConvertible {
  public var description: String {
      return "x: \(x), y: \(y), z: \(z)"
  }
}
```

Is there a good way to automatically synthesise this repetitive code?

Comment: Have a look at [Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery)